# make4ht diplaystyle \dfrac command

Tags: tex4ht, displaystyle, make4ht

Is it possible to make the \dfrac command work in inline mode?  Or is it possible to force all the math in diplaystyle mode ? I use make4ht with mathml.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\frac12$ $\dfrac22$  $\displaystyle \frac32$
\[  \frac{4}{2} \]
\end{document}
```

I use the command line `make4ht file.tex "mathml"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, information about math style is available in the underlying `genfrac` configuration, which can be used to enclose the `dfrac` contents in an element with `displaystyle="true"` attribute:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\pend:def\dfrac{\Configure{genfrac}{\HCode{<mstyle \mathchoice{displaystyle="true"}{}{}{}>}}{}{}{}{}{\HCode{</mstyle>}}}
\pend:def\tfrac{\Configure{genfrac}{\HCode{<mstyle \mathchoice{displaystyle="false"}{}{}{}>}}{}{}{}{}{\HCode{</mstyle>}}}
\pend:def\dbinom{\Configure{genfrac}{\HCode{<mstyle \mathchoice{displaystyle="true"}{}{}{}>}}{}{}{}{}{\HCode{</mstyle>}}}
\pend:def\tbinom{\Configure{genfrac}{\HCode{<mstyle \mathchoice{displaystyle="false"}{}{}{}>}}{}{}{}{}{\HCode{</mstyle>}}}
\catcode`\:=12
%\Configure{$}{\Configure{@math}{display="inline"}\DviMath\@mathstyle{0}}{\EndDviMath}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

In this configuration, we add the `<mrow>` element, and using the `\mathchoice` command, we can add the `displaystyle` attribute. This is the result:

[image]

If you want to use displaystyle for all inline math delimited by `$ $`, use this configuration:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{$}{\Configure{@math}{display="inline" displaystyle="true"}\DviMath}{\EndDviMath}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

[image]

The downside is that it can be too large when used in text.

Comment: Thanks for your reactivity, but the first code don't work for me with Mathml+mathjax

Comment: I try to use Mathml+mathjax  for more compatibility

Comment: @ManuelCart it seems that MathJax needs `<mstyle>` instead of `<mrow>`. I've updated my answer with the solution that I used in the end in TeX4ht sources.

Comment: I have a new problem with the new code, maybe it is related,. i post it here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669428/make4ht-error-with-mathml-mathjax-and-packages-tasks-amsmath